# Syntax for Objective-C property of block-type (without typedef)

Tags: objective-c, properties, typedef, objective-c-blocks

The syntax for declaring a property referring to a block is:

```
typedef void (^voidBlock)();
@property (nonatomic, copy) voidBlock callback;
...
@synthesize callback;
```

How could this be done without the typedef?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^callback)();
```